Define data type in creating custom function
I have below custom function
import pandas as pd
def MyFn(DF : pd.DataFrame) -> float :
  return DF['Col_A'].values[1] - DF['Col_B'].values[1]

However I want to force user to supply a dataframe with 2 columns and having column names as 'Col_A' and 'Col_B'
Any insight how can I do it would be very appreciated.

Force how? Would assert DF.columns.tolist() == ['Col_A', 'Col_B'] work for you?

It is working. However is there any way to put such condition within DF : pd.DataFrame framework?

If you mean using typing, this wouldn't prevent you from passing incorrect data. For instance MyFn({'Col_A': pd.Series([0, 1]), 'Col_B': pd.Series([4, 5])}) would not raise an exception even though we passed a dictionary and not a DataFrame.

You should be able to use assert and DF.columns.tolist() == ['Col_A', 'Col_B']:
def MyFn(DF : pd.DataFrame) -> float :
    assert DF.columns.tolist() == ['Col_A', 'Col_B'], 'DF must have two columns named "Col_A" and "Col_B"'
    return DF['Col_A'].values[1] - DF['Col_B'].values[1]

MyFn(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 5]], columns=['Col_A', 'Col_B']))
# -2

MyFn(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 5]], columns=['Col_A', 'Col_C']))
# AssertionError: DF must have two columns named "Col_A" and "Col_B"

MyFn(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 7]], columns=['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C']))
# AssertionError: DF must have two columns named "Col_A" and "Col_B"

Note that this would require exactly two columns, "Col_A" and "Col_B", in this particular order.
A more flexible option would be to use try/except, which would allow you to handle another potential error independently: the fact that passing a DataFrame with less that two rows would trigger an IndexError:
def MyFn(DF : pd.DataFrame) -> float :
    try:
        return DF['Col_A'].values[1] - DF['Col_B'].values[1]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise Exception('DF must contain "Col_A" and "Col_B"') from e
    except IndexError as e:
        raise Exception('DF must have at least two rows') from e

MyFn(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 5]], columns=['Col_A', 'Col_B']))
# -2

#MyFn(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 5]], columns=['Col_A', 'Col_C']))
# Exception: DF must contain "Col_A" and "Col_B"

MyFn(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 7]], columns=['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C']))
# -2

MyFn(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=['Col_A', 'Col_B']))
# Exception: DF must have at least two rows


Here is my method
I use a try function to prevent an exception, this is an easy way to fix it and more flexible
import pandas as pd
def MyFn(DF : pd.DataFrame) -> float :
  try:
    return DF['Col_A'].values[1] - DF['Col_B'].values[1]
  except:
    print("you must include 'Col_A' and 'Col_B' in the argument!")
    return 0.0 # I would like to return something to prevent error


Hope this solves the problem.
